# Outlook drag and drop shadow

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, drag-and-drop

After drag-and-drop'ing a Mail from Outlook to an "Browse" dialog from Firefox, but then actually deciding against dropping it, I still have a shadow item like this:

[image]

Things I tried that did not help so far

- restarting outlook
- shooting into the dark: restarting the graphics driver (<kbd>WIN</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>)
- kill my users explorer.exe process

I suspect a logout or reboot would solve this, but is there another way?

I tried searching for a workaround, but did not find the correct keywords to get any useful results.

Answer (score 1):

Forgot the obvious thing: Restarting the target application (Firefox); that helped.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.